# How to write the sum of r^(α+1) in terms of the sum of r^(α-1)?

Tags: summation

The sum from 1 to n of r^(α+1), {α,n} $\in ℕ $, can be written as the sum from 1 to n of the sum from x to n of r^α.

$$\underset{r = 1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}r^{\alpha + 1} = \underset{x = 1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}\underset{r = x}{\overset{n}{\sum }}r^\alpha$$
How can one write the sum from 1 to n of r^(α+1) in terms of anything less than α, since trying to write the sum of a sum of a sum would be using the same variable x repeatedly.

Main question: How can one write $\underset{r = 1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}r^{\alpha + 1}$ in terms of $r^{\alpha - 1}$.

Then: How can one write it more generally, in terms of $r^{\beta}$, where $\alpha > \beta$ and $\beta \in ℕ $

In case the above didn't make sense, an example:
$$\underset{r = 1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}r^4 = \underset{x = 1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}\underset{r = x}{\overset{n}{\sum }}r^3$$

How does one write $\underset{r = 1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}r^4$ in terms of $\underset{r = 1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}r^2$ or $\underset{r = 1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}r$, as substituting ($\underset{r = 1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}r^3 = \underset{x = 1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}\underset{r = x}{\overset{n}{\sum }}r^2$) into $\underset{r = 1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}r^4$ doesn't work directly, since the variable x is used more than once.
$$\underset{r = 1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}r^4 \neq \underset{x = 1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}\underset{x = 1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}\underset{r = x}{\overset{n}{\sum }}r^2$$
Changing the second summation's bounds also doesn't work to fix the problem.

I realised that putting brackets around the substituted sums will solve the problem, but could it be simplified further in terms of summations of summations of summations... instead of putting brackets around the substituted in equivalences of lower and lower powers. Can the summation be altered to compensated for the substituted summation of summations instead?

^**That's some what true, but the problem of variables remain even if you used brackets, only just remembered why I ruled out that answer in this 2nd edit**

Using sum of differences can give you the general formula of summations of natural numbers to natural powers, but how could we express the general formulae of an arbitrarily large power in terms of any smaller powers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way
of generating the successive formulas
for the sums of powers
in terms of the sums
of previous powers
I came up with
a while ago.
This is obviously not original,
and was probably known to Bernoulli,
but it was found independently
by me.

If
$f_k(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i^k$
($f_0(n) = n$)
then

$f_{k}(n)
=\dfrac1{k+1}\left((n+1)^{k+1}-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j}f_j(n)\right)
$

Proof.

$\begin{array}\\
f_k(n+1) 
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^k\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n} (i+1)^k\\
&=1+ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (i+1)^k\\
&=1+ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}i^j\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^j\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)\\
\text{so}\\
(n+1)^k
&=f_{k}(n+1)-f_k(n)\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)-f_k(n)\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)\\
\text{or}\\
kf_{k-1}(n)
&=(n+1)^k-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-2} \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)\\
\text{or}\\
(k+1)f_{k}(n)
&=(n+1)^{k+1}-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j}f_j(n)\\
\text{or}\\
f_{k}(n)
&=\dfrac1{k+1}\left((n+1)^{k+1}-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j}f_j(n)\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Note that
this shows that
if $f_j(n)$
is a polynomial of degree $j+1$
for $0 \le j \le k-1$
then
$f_k(n)$
is a polynomial of degree
$k+1$.

Here are the first few cases.

$\begin{array}\\
\\
k=1\\
2f_{1}(n)
&=(n+1)^{2}-1-f_0(n)\\
&=n^2+2n+1-1-n\\
&=n^2+n\\
f_1(n)
&=\dfrac{n^2+n}{2}\\
\\
k=2\\
3f_{2}(n)
&=(n+1)^{3}-1-f_0(n)-3f_1(n)\\
&=n^3+3n^2+3n+1-1-n-3(n^2+n)/2\\
&=\dfrac{2n^3+6n^2+6n+2-2-2n-3(n^2+n)}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{2}\\
f_{2}(n)
&=\dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}\\
&=\dfrac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}\\
\\
k=3\\
4f_{3}(n)
&=(n+1)^{4}-1-f_0(n)-4f_1(n)-6f_2(n)\\
&=n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1-1-n-4\dfrac{n^2+n}{2}-6\dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}\\
&=n^4+4n^3+6n^2+3n-2(n^2+n)-(2n^3+3n^2+n)\\
&=n^4+2n^3+n^2\\
&=n^2(n^2+2n+1)\\
&=n^2(n+1)^2\\
f_3(n)
&=\dfrac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}\\
&=\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2\\
\\
k=4\\
5f_{4}(n)
&=(n+1)^{5}-1-f_0(n)-5f_1(n)-10f_2(n)-10f_3(n)\\
&=n^5+5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n+1-1-n-5\dfrac{n^2+n}{2}-10\dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}-10\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2\\
&=n^5 + \dfrac{5 n^4}{2} + \dfrac{5 n^3}{3} - \dfrac{n}{6}\\
&=\dfrac{6n^5 + 15 n^4 + 10 n^3 - n}{6}\\
&=\dfrac{ n (2 n + 1) (n + 1) (3 n^2 + 3 n - 1)}{6}\\
f_4(n)
&=\dfrac{ n (2 n + 1) (n + 1) (3 n^2 + 3 n - 1)}{30}\\
&=\dfrac{6n^5 + 15 n^4 + 10 n^3 - n}{30}\\
&=\dfrac{n^5}{5} + \dfrac{ n^4}{2} + \dfrac{ n^3}{3} - \dfrac{n}{30}\\
\end{array}
$

Continuing this,
here is a first step
to discovering the
Bernoulli numbers.

If
$f_j(n)
=\sum_{i=1}^{j+1} c_{j, i} n^i
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
c_{0, 1..1}
&=1\\
c_{1, 1..2}
&=\dfrac12. \dfrac12\\
c_{2, 1..3}
&=\dfrac16. \dfrac12, \dfrac13\\
c_{3, 1..4}
&=0, \dfrac14. \dfrac12, \dfrac14\\
c_{4, 1..5}
&=- \dfrac1{30}, 0, \dfrac13. \dfrac12, \dfrac15\\
\end{array}
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
(k+1)f_{k}(n)
&=(n+1)^{k+1}-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j}f_j(n)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{j}n^j-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j}\sum_{i=1}^{j+1} c_{j, i} n^i\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{j}n^j-\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=i-1}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j} c_{j, i} n^i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{i}n^i-\sum_{i=1}^{k}n^i\sum_{j=i-1}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j} c_{j, i}\\
&=n^{k+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}\binom{k+1}{i}n^i-\sum_{i=1}^{k}n^i\sum_{j=i-1}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j} c_{j, i}\\
&=n^{k+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}n^i\left(\binom{k+1}{i}-\sum_{j=i-1}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j} c_{j, i}\right)\\
\text{so}\\
(k+1)c_{k, k+1}
&=1\\
c_{k, k+1}
&=\dfrac1{k+1}\\
\text{for } 1 \le i \le k\\
(k+1)c_{k, i}
&=\binom{k+1}{i}-\sum_{j=i-1}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j} c_{j, i}\\(k+1)c_{k, k}
&=\binom{k+1}{k}-\sum_{j=k-1}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j} c_{j, k}\\
&=k+1-\binom{k+1}{k-1} c_{k-1, k}\\
&=k+1-\dfrac{k(k+1)}{2}\dfrac1{k}\\
&=k+1-\dfrac{k+1}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{k+1}{2}\\
c_{k, k}
&=\dfrac12\\
\\
(k+1)c_{k, i}
&=\binom{k+1}{i}-\sum_{j=i-1}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j} c_{j, i}\\(k+1)c_{k, k-1}
&=\binom{k+1}{k-1}-\sum_{j=k-2}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j} c_{j, k-1}\\
&=\dfrac{(k+1)k}{2}-\binom{k+1}{k-2} c_{k-2, k-1}-\binom{k+1}{k-1} c_{k-1, k-1}\\
&=\dfrac{(k+1)k}{2}-\dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)}{6} c_{k-2, k-1}-\dfrac{(k+1)k}{2}\dfrac12\\
&=\dfrac{(k+1)k}{4}-\dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)}{6} c_{k-2, k-1}\\
c_{k, k-1}
&=\dfrac{k}{4}-\dfrac{k(k-1)}{6} c_{k-2, k-1}\\
&=\dfrac{k}{4}-\dfrac{k(k-1)}{6} \dfrac1{k-1}\\
&=\dfrac{k}{4}-\dfrac{k}{6}\\
&=\dfrac{k}{12}\\
\\
(k+1)c_{k, i}
&=\binom{k+1}{i}-\sum_{j=i-1}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j} c_{j, i}\\(k+1)c_{k, k-2}
&=\binom{k+1}{k-2}-\sum_{j=k-3}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j} c_{j, k-2}\\
&=\binom{k+1}{k-2}- \binom{k+1}{k-3} c_{k-3, k-2}-\binom{k+1}{k-2} c_{k-2, k-2}-\binom{k+1}{k-1} c_{k-1, k-2}\\
&=\dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)}{6}- \dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)(k-2)}{24}\dfrac1{k-2}-\dfrac{(k+1)(k(k-1)}{6}\dfrac12-\dfrac{(k+1)k}{2}\dfrac{k-1}{12}\\
&=\dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)}{6}- \dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)}{24}-\dfrac{(k+1)(k(k-1)}{12}-\dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)}{24}\\
c_{k, k-2}
&=\dfrac{k(k-1)}{6}- \dfrac{k(k-1)}{24}-\dfrac{k(k-1)}{12}-\dfrac{k(k-1)}{24}\\
&=0\\
\\
(k+1)c_{k, i}
&=\binom{k+1}{i}-\sum_{j=i-1}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j} c_{j, i}\\(k+1)c_{k, k-3}
&=\binom{k+1}{k-3}-\sum_{j=k-4}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j} c_{j, k-3}\\
&=\binom{k+1}{k-3}\\
&- \binom{k+1}{k-4} c_{k-4, k-3}\\
&-\binom{k+1}{k-3} c_{k-3, k-3}\\
&-\binom{k+1}{k-2} c_{k-2, k-3}\\
&-\binom{k+1}{k-1} c_{k-1, k-3}\\
&=\dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)(k-2)}{24}\\
&- \dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)}{120}\dfrac1{k-3}\\
&-\dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)(k-2)}{24}\dfrac12\\
&-\dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)}{6}\dfrac{k-2}{12}\\
&-\dfrac{(k+1)k}{2}0\\
&=\dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)(k-2)}{24}\\
&- \dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)(k-2)}{120}\\
&-\dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)(k-2)}{48}\\
&-\dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)(k-2)}{72}\\
&=(k+1)k(k-1)(k-2)(\dfrac1{24}
- \dfrac1{120}
-\dfrac1{48}
-\dfrac1{72})\\
&=-\dfrac{(k+1)k(k-1)(k-2)}{720}\\
c_{k, k-3}
&=-\dfrac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{720}\\
\\
c_{k, k+1}
&=\dfrac1{k+1}\\
c_{k, k}
&=\dfrac12\\
c_{k, k-j}
&=b_j\prod_{i=0}^{j-1}(k-i) \\
&=b_j\dfrac{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(k-i)}{\prod_{i=j}^{k-1}(k-i)} \\
&=b_j\dfrac{k!}{\prod_{i=1}^{k-j}(i)} \\
&=b_j\dfrac{k!}{(k-j)!} \\
&=j!b_j\binom{k}{j} \\
b_{1, 2, 3}
&=\dfrac1{12}, 
 0, -\dfrac1{720}\\ 
b_j(j+1)!
&=\dfrac12, 0, -\dfrac1{30}\\
\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thanks for the informative solution to the general formula of summations of natural numbers to an arbitrary power, however, is there no possible way of writing them as summations of lower powered summations? Sorry if my question wasn't worded as well as it should, but I'm mainly in search for a way of writing the summations of some large power as that of the summation of lower powers, not a general way of expressing the solution of the summations of larger powers in terms of a polynomial, that part was interesting to understand, but not what I was in search for.

Comment: I see that you can write the summation of a larger power in terms of lower powers, but is it not possible to do so as a larger summation, since the above is just adding and subtracting previously lower powers to get the new larger power.

Comment: You might be able to apply this iteratively to the summation each time removing one power.